# Find number of numbers made with 1,2,3,4 such that same digits never lie together

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

> There is a particular sequence only uses the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and no two adjacent numbers are the same.
>   Write a program that given n1 1s, n2 2s, n3 3s, n4 4s will output the number of such sequences using all these numbers.
>   Output your answer modulo 1000000007 (10^9 + 7).

I found this question on geeksforgeeks.com.

The naive approach of printing all such solutions will take O(4^n). can there be a better solution using dynamic programming?

I tried running the following code for DP. Gives the wrong answer. Can anyone suggest improvement?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int d1[50][50][50][50],d2[50][50][50][50],d3[50][50][50][50],d4[50][50][50][50];

int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    n1=2;n2=2;n3=1;n4=2;
    d1[1][0][0][0]=1;
    d2[0][1][0][0]=1;
    d3[0][0][1][0]=1;
    d4[0][0][0][1]=1;
    for(int i=0;i<=n1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=n2;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<=n3;k++){
                for(int l=0;l<=n4;l++){
                    if(i)d1[i][j][k][l]=d2[i-1][j][k][l]+d3[i-1][j][k][l]+d4[i-1][j][k][l];
                    if(j)d2[i][j][k][l]=d1[i][j-1][k][l]+d3[i][j-1][k][l]+d4[i][j-1][k][l];
                    if(k)d3[i][j][k][l]=d2[i][j][k-1][l]+d1[i][j][k-1][l]+d4[i][j][k-1][l];
                    if(l)d4[i][j][k][l]=d2[i][j][k][l-1]+d3[i][j][k][l-1]+d1[i][j][k][l-1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<d1[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d2[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d3[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d4[n1][n2][n3][n4];
}
```

Comment: Probably off-topic here. Try asking at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or maybe http://cs.stackexchange.com/. There are so many now, it's sometimes hard to decide where to post....But def not here. This site requires code already written but not working. I think...:)

Comment: In your example you rewrite `dp` that you've initialized in loop. Easy way to solve this is to update `dp` if `i+j+k+l > 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:
let `dpX[i][j][k][l]` stand for the number of such sequences that ends with `X`, `X` is 1,2,3 or 4 with `i` ones, `j` twos, `k` threes, `l` fours. Then you'll have the formula for `dp1`:

```
dp1[i][j][k][l] = dp2[i-1][j][k][l] + dp3[i-1][j][k][l] + dp4[i-1][j][k][l]
```

And the analogous for `dp2`, `dp3` and `dp4`. The answer will be the `dp1[n1][n2][n3][n4] + 
dp2[n1][n2][n3][n4] + dp3[n1][n2][n3][n4] + dp4[n1][n2][n3][n4]`.

The time complexity is `O(n1*n2*n3*n4)`.

Comment: Can you tell me how will you implement it? It requires values of dp1,dp2,dp3 and dp4 simultaneously. How can you update them simultaneously?

Comment: You can run it in four consecutive cycles: by i, j, k and l.

Comment: I wrote my code in the question. Can you suggest some changes? I am a beginner. Excuse my mistakes.

Comment: Maybe you forgot that you need answer `mod 1e9+7`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code requires the condition (i + j + k + l > 1) else it makes
dp4[0][0][0][1] = 0. This applies to other dpX too.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int d1[50][50][50][50],d2[50][50][50][50],d3[50][50][50][50],d4[50][50][50][50];

#define MOD 1000000007

int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);
    d1[1][0][0][0]=1;
    d2[0][1][0][0]=1;
    d3[0][0][1][0]=1;
    d4[0][0][0][1]=1;
    for(int i=0;i<=n1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=n2;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<=n3;k++){
                for(int l=0;l<=n4;l++){
                    if (i + j + k + l > 1) {
                    if(i)d1[i][j][k][l]=d2[i-1][j][k][l]+d3[i-1][j][k][l]+d4[i-1][j][k][l] % MOD;
                    if(j)d2[i][j][k][l]=d1[i][j-1][k][l]+d3[i][j-1][k][l]+d4[i][j-1][k][l] % MOD;
                    if(k)d3[i][j][k][l]=d2[i][j][k-1][l]+d1[i][j][k-1][l]+d4[i][j][k-1][l] % MOD;
                    if(l)d4[i][j][k][l]=d2[i][j][k][l-1]+d3[i][j][k][l-1]+d1[i][j][k][l-1] % MOD;
                }
                }
             }
        }
    }
    cout<<d1[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d2[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d3[n1][n2][n3][n4]+d4[n1][n2][n3][n4] % MOD << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following approach is using 4 dimension arrays to store how many number of particular sequence without adjacent.

dp1[i][j][k][l] : how many number of particular sequence without adjacent end with 1 and has i 1s, j 2s, k 3s, l 4s.

dp2[i][j][k][l] : how many number of particular sequence without adjacent end with 2 and has i 1s, j 2s, k 3s, l 4s.

So dp1[i][j][k][l] = dp2[i – 1][j][k][l] + dp3[i – 1][j][k][l] +dp4[i – 1][j][k][l];
dp1 would be the sum of i – 1 1s end with 2(dp2), 3(dp3), 4(dp4);

```
public int Sequence(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4)
        {
            var dp1 = new int[n1 + 1, n2 + 1, n3 + 1, n4 + 1];
            var dp2 = new int[n1 + 1, n2 + 1, n3 + 1, n4 + 1];
            var dp3 = new int[n1 + 1, n2 + 1, n3 + 1, n4 + 1];
            var dp4 = new int[n1 + 1, n2 + 1, n3 + 1, n4 + 1];

            const int MOD = 1000000007;
            dp1[1, 0, 0, 0] = 1;
            dp2[0, 1, 0, 0] = 1;
            dp3[0, 0, 1, 0] = 1;
            dp4[0, 0, 0, 1] = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= n2; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k <= n3; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l <= n4; l++)                                        {                             
                            if (i + j + k + l > 1)
                            {
                                if (i > 0) dp1[i, j, k, l] = dp2[i - 1, j, k, l] + dp3[i - 1, j, k, l] + dp4[i - 1, j, k, l] % MOD;
                                if (j > 0) dp2[i, j, k, l] = dp1[i, j - 1, k, l] + dp3[i, j - 1, k, l] + dp4[i, j - 1, k, l] % MOD;
                                if (k > 0) dp3[i, j, k, l] = dp2[i, j, k - 1, l] + dp1[i, j, k - 1, l] + dp4[i, j, k - 1, l] % MOD;
                                if (l > 0) dp4[i, j, k, l] = dp2[i, j, k, l - 1] + dp3[i, j, k, l - 1] + dp1[i, j, k, l - 1] % MOD;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return dp1[n1, n2, n3, n4] + dp2[n1, n2, n3, n4] + dp3[n1, n2, n3, n4] + dp4[n1, n2, n3, n4] % MOD;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the logic, but there is small bug in it. Look at second iteration itself when i=0, j=0, k=0, l=1 : we have  d4[0][0][0][1] = 0. i.e, the base case is being modified and hence answer comes to be 0. A quick fix for this problem could be in the innermost loop after updating all d's add 4 base cases once again. This fixes it. If anyone have any better idea do comment it.

Comment: So, what you're suggesting is adding up all di's [i][j][k][l] and returning the total sum after all the iterations? I added t+=d1[i][j][k][l]+d2[i][j][k][l]+d3[i][j][k][l]+d4[i][j][k][l]; statement. But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution wont handle for large element..this solution will be work with all test cases.. Tested :)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
int d1[21][21][21][21],d2[21][21][21][21],d3[21][21][21][21],d4[21][21][21][21];

#define MOD 1000000007

int main(){
ll n1,n2,n3,n4;
cin>>n1>>n2>>n3>>n4;
d1[1][0][0][0]=1;
d2[0][1][0][0]=1;
d3[0][0][1][0]=1;
d4[0][0][0][1]=1;
for(int i=0;i<=n1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=n2;j++){
        for(int k=0;k<=n3;k++){
            for(int l=0;l<=n4;l++){
                if (i + j + k + l > 1) {
                if(i>0)d1[i][j][k][l]=(d2[i-1][j][k][l] % MOD +d3[i-1][j][k][l]% MOD+d4[i-1][j][k][l]% MOD) % MOD;
                if(j>0)d2[i][j][k][l]=(d1[i][j-1][k][l] % MOD+d3[i][j-1][k][l]% MOD+d4[i][j-1][k][l]% MOD )% MOD;
                if(k>0)d3[i][j][k][l]=(d2[i][j][k-1][l] % MOD+d1[i][j][k-1][l] % MOD+d4[i][j][k-1][l]% MOD) % MOD;
                if(l>0)d4[i][j][k][l]=(d2[i][j][k][l-1] % MOD+d3[i][j][k][l-1] % MOD+d1[i][j][k][l-1]% MOD) % MOD;
            }
            }
         }
    }
}
cout<<(d1[n1][n2][n3][n4]% MOD+d2[n1][n2][n3][n4]% MOD+d3[n1][n2][n3][n4]% MOD+d4[n1][n2][n3][n4]% MOD) % MOD << endl;
}
```